# Google Bigquery Memory error when using ROW_NUMBER() on large table - ways to replace long hash by short unique identifier

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-order-by, uniqueidentifier, row-number

For a query in google BigQuery I want to replace a long hash by a shorter numeric unique identifier to save some memory afterwards, so I do:

```
SELECT 
    my_hash
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY null) AS id_numeric
FROM hash_table_raw
GROUP BY my_hash
```

I don't even need an order in the id, but `ROW_NUMBER()` requires an `ORDER BY`.

When I try this on my dataset (> 1 billion rows) I get a memory error:

```
400 Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 126% of limit.
Top memory consumer(s):
  sort operations used for analytic OVER() clauses: 99%
  other/unattributed: 1%
```

Is there another way to replace a hash by an shorter identifier?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One does not really need to have populated over clause while doing this.

e.g. following will work:

```
select col, row_number() over() as row_num from (select 'A' as col)
```

So that will be your first try.

Now, with billion+ rows that you have: if above fails: you can do something like this (considering order is not at all important for you): but here you have to do it in parts:

```
SELECT 
    my_hash
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id_numeric
FROM hash_table_raw
where MOD(my_hash, 5) = 0
```

And in subsequent queries:
you can get max(id_numeric) from previous run and add that as an offset to next:

```
SELECT 
    my_hash
    , previous_max_id_numberic_val + ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id_numeric
FROM hash_table_raw
where MOD(my_hash, 5) = 1
```

And keep appending outputs of these mod queries (0-4) to a single new table.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the first suggestion does not work and for the second - which looked promising - I get: `No matching signature for function MOD for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signatures: MOD(INT64, INT64); MOD(NUMERIC, NUMERIC); MOD(BIGNUMERIC, BIGNUMERIC)`

Comment: you can work around like this as example: SELECT my_hash , previous_max_id_numberic_val + ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id_numeric FROM hash_table_raw where MOD(farm_fingerprint(my_hash), 5) = 1